# Не могу нормально разархивировать архив с помощью c#

Tags: c#, winrar

В моей программе я использую сам Winrar для извлечения файлов из архивов

```
          try
          {
              ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
              ps.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRar.exe";
              ps.Arguments = @"e D:\test\test.rar D:\test\123";
              Process.Start(ps);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
          }
```

Но извлечение файлов идет не правильно,нет папок.Тоесть все файлы просто извлекаются без папок.
Получается так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно быть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может что-то в коде не правильно или архив не верно запакован,я уже и не знаю что делать.

Comment: Наверно не `e`, а `x` (судя по [документации](http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/index.html?page=html%2Fhelpcommands.htm))?

Comment: Все,разобрался,сделал через Zipfile

Comment: Тоже вполне  возможно